# 13" MacBook Pro mid 2014 no startup key combination works - unable to update or enter recovery mode

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, software-update, recovery

I have catalina installed and can't update to big sur ("update not found / the requested version of macOS is not available) so i wanted to do fresh install from recovery mode but after trying all possible options I can't get anywhere. any combination of cmd R option/alt shift doesn't work. the only startup key combination that works is cmd+S. I also tried with bootable USB devices but the option/alt key doesn't work to select boot option. i tried with a live kali usb still not working. both those USB work on my MBA or iMac.

I tried the built in keyboard as well as my magic keyboard.

The only difference that I can see in Disk Utility is that the problematic MBP has "2 not mounted" compared to the other 2 and its the Preboot that is not mounted.

I really don't know what else to do.

Update: I found out there might be an issue with Big Sur on some 2013-2014 models and that might be the reason for the update issue, but that's not my main issue. I want a clean instal and ssd format for the MBP and I can't find any solution to go into recovery mode nor internet recovery. I tried holding them before I power on , just after, after the chime, I tried almost everything and nothing works.

UPDATE 2: I managed to get into recovery mode using the below command, thanks to a different question here.

```
sudo nvram "recovery-boot-mode=unused"
```

I installed a fresh copy of Catalina but I still cant get into recovery mode by just holding cmd+R or into startup manager by holding option/alt.

Comment: The 2014 MacBooks have recently been excluded from Big Sur compatibility after many of them were bricked, requiring new logic boards to fix. https://www.macrumors.com/2020/11/15/macos-big-sur-update-bricking-some-macbook-pros/ & various other reports, including https://www.forbes.com/sites/barrycollins/2020/11/20/macbook-bricked-by-big-sur-heres-how-to-fix-it/ . i'd stick with Catalina for now.

Comment: oh, thank you, i didn't know that, but my booting problems remain which is annoying as I want a clean instal of OS and....absolutely nothing works.

Comment: I'd see if a wired keyboard might work… though I'm worried even the internal keyboard won't register startup commands & suspect you may have a stuck key.

Comment: I tried with my magic keyboard (wired connection) and no luck

Comment: I think next stop might be a repair shop.